# How can I represent Pauli Measurements in Qiskit's QuantumCircuit object?

Tags: programming, qiskit

Is there a way to represent measurements in other bases in Qiskit? The default measurement is in the Z (computational) basis. Can I also depict measurement in X, Y and general Pauli Measurements?

I know that I can apply a suitable unitary and then measure in the Z basis, but I am looking for a way to add the measurements to the circuit almost like "gates". I will be putting many such measurements in sequence in my circuits.
I will be happy to use any external/in-development tool that allows this and interfaces well with Qiskit.

Comment: In progress:  https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/5311

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick answer. Do you think that is ready to use for what I have said I want to do?

Comment: Probably, but I don't think it will be easy for you to apply it without a proper release of Qiskit that includes it.

Comment: Have you looked into using Pennylane? They allow you to measure in arbitrary basis as you mentioned.... look here: https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction/measurements.html  and there is a plugin between Pennylane and Qiskit https://pennylane-qiskit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  which allows you to execute your work on IBM hardware.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thanks for sharing! Unfortunately it looks like while Pennylane does allow the general Pauli measurements I want, it still does not allow multiple measurements per circuit.

Comment: @YaelBen-Haim Is there any chance that the meas_pauli branch could be used something like this: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16007/13497 ?

Comment: Hello @user3717194, how about something like this: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/how-to-measure-in-another-basis ? You create functions for measurements you want and apply them at the end of the circuit, would that be a good enough temporary solution for you? You can also use the idea to create custom gates like [composite gates here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/01_advanced_circuits.html#Composite-Gates) by creating a circuit and transform it into instruction you apply as gates on any circuit. Is it helpful?

Comment: By the way, there is a lab available on the Qiskit textbook about Quantum Measurement, maybe it'll help you, here https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-labs/Lab02_QuantumMeasurement.html,

Comment: You can use the branch by installing qiskit-terra from source

Comment: Hi @YaelBen-Haim , are the features to draw Pauli Measurements ready? I tried building from source but am getting errors when I try to draw the circuit:
circuit = QuantumCircuit(6, 6)
circuit.measure_pauli('x', [0], [0])
display(circuit.draw())

Comment: @Lena those are some interesting ideas, thanks for sharing. For the moment I'll try other methods but might return to your ideas.

Comment: Did you checkout the relevant pull request?  It's not in the master branch.

Comment: Yes I believe so, here is the error message I am getting if that helps.

...
~/anaconda3/envs/paulimeas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/visualization/text.py in _instruction_to_gate(self, instruction, layer)
   1002                 gate = MeasureFrom()
   1003             else:   # measure_pauli
-> 1004                 basis = instruction.params.upper()
   1005                 gate = MeasureFrom(basis)
   1006             layer.set_qubit(instruction.qargs[0], gate)

AttributeError: 'DAGNode' object has no attribute 'params'