# How to use qiskit transpile with Clifford + T basis?

Tags: programming, qiskit, universal-gates

How can I transpile using universal $Clifford + T$ gates set? I have only seen examples using rotations + $CNOT$.

This is what I have tried

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
%matplotlib inline

u = Operator([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.unitary(u, [0,1,2], label='u')

result = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx'], optimization_level=3)
result.draw(output='mpl')
```

And this example works fine. But when I was trying to set:

```
basis_gates=['h', 's', 't', 'cx']
```

It doesn't work.
Could you help me, please?)

UPDATE:
After comments I've tried this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/LNoorl/qiskit-terra.git@feature/sk-pass
```

and then:

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import TGate, HGate, TdgGate, SGate
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import SolovayKitaevDecomposition
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
%matplotlib inline

u = Operator([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.unitary(u, [0,1,2], label='u')

print('Orginal circuit:')
print(qc)

basis_gates = [TGate(), SGate(), HGate()]
skd = SolovayKitaevDecomposition(recursion_degree=2, basis_gates=basis_gates, depth=5)

discretized = skd(qc)

print('Discretized circuit:')
print(discretized)
```

But it outputs only this:

```
Orginal circuit:
     ┌────┐
q_0: ┤0   ├
     │    │
q_1: ┤1 u ├
     │    │
q_2: ┤2   ├
     └────┘
Discretized circuit:
     ┌────┐
q_0: ┤0   ├
     │    │
q_1: ┤1 u ├
     │    │
q_2: ┤2   ├
     └────┘
```

Where is a problem?

Comment: I need to use H, S, T, CNOT gates.

Comment: You can decompose your circuit in CNOT and single qubit gates with `transpile(circuit, basis_gates=['u', 'cx'])` and then you just need to find a Clifford+T approximation, which is discussed in the question @luciano referred to. Since Clifford includes S and H that gives you the H, S, T and CNOT basis.

Comment: I have updated the question)

Comment: Try the decompose method on the circuit, something like `qc.decompose().draw()` would show you the inside of your black box

Comment: It shows  me ```      ┌───────────┐
q_0: ┤0          ├
     │           │
q_1: ┤1 ISOMETRY ├
     │           │
q_2: ┤2          ├
     └───────────┘ ```

Comment: So it looks like this skd implementation can't work with arbitrary unitary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your second result is because unitary synthesis is not part of the `SolovayKitaevDecomposition` pass. Actually, you can combine your attempts to get the desired result.

This is the first stage (you first snippet), it will synthesise your circuit in terms of `u*` and `cx`:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.compiler import transpile

u = Operator([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.unitary(u, [0,1,2], label='u')

transpiled = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx'], optimization_level=3)
```

Then you can transform it to Cliffort+T using `SolovayKitaevDecomposition`:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import TGate, HGate, SGate
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import SolovayKitaevDecomposition

basis_gates = [TGate(), SGate(), HGate()]
skd = SolovayKitaevDecomposition(recursion_degree=3, basis_gates=basis_gates, depth=5)
discretized = skd(transpiled)
print(discretized)
```

```
global phase: -0.063526
     ┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐                           »
q_0: ┤ X ├┤ T ├┤ X ├┤ S ├┤ X ├┤ X ├┤ S ├┤ S ├┤ H ├───────────────────────────»
     └─┬─┘└───┘└─┬─┘└───┘└─┬─┘└─┬─┘├───┤├───┤├───┤┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌─────┐»
q_1: ──■─────────┼─────────■────┼──┤ X ├┤ S ├┤ S ├┤ S ├┤ X ├┤ S ├┤ H ├┤ TDG ├»
                 │              │  └─┬─┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└─┬─┘├───┤├───┤└┬───┬┘»
q_2: ────────────■──────────────■────■───────────────────■──┤ T ├┤ S ├─┤ S ├─»
                                                            └───┘└───┘ └───┘ »
```

Comment: Hey, I can't seem to find this module in Qiskit currently, is there a feature in qiskit that can perform clifford + T compilation?

Comment: It's in a not-yet merged PR https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/5657 Check out https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16007/1859 for details on how to run it